# Lizards with advanced intelligence (dinosaurs) in a cylindrical spaceship flying towards earth

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, artificial-gravity

I read the book in the late 80's.

I believe that the huge "ship" was a pre-programmed vessel that was heading back to Earth with a collection of intelligent lizards/dinosaurs as the cargo. If I remember correctly, the ship created its own centrifugal gravity and was described as a test-tube of life from a former time on earth, or as an alternate developmental path to human development on earth. Sort of a "what-if" the reptilian life had been allowed to evolve instead of being wiped out.

Answer (score 4):

I think that might be [*Toolmaker Koan*](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Toolmaker_Koan.html?id=rwFMOwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) by John McLoughlin, which to the best of my memory (and it's probably 20 years since I read it) matches your description.

Edited to add that I found a review [here](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2143965.Toolmaker_Koan) (behind a spoiler tag) that seems to agree with my memory. I'm pretty sure this is the book you're looking for.